# UPDATE/INSERT data to sql database not working and no errors

Tags: php, html, sql

I can retrieve data but not update or insert, my code looks fine but still doesn't work.

I am using mysql_query.

Insert query did not work and no Error finding by php  but select worked fine.

This is my PHP code :

```
if(isset($_POST['txtBrName'])){
    if(isset($_POST['hdn']) && $_POST['hdn'] == '0'){
    $sql_branch = "INSERT INTO `tblbranch`(`branch_name`, `b_email`, `b_contact_no`, `b_address`,`b_status`) VALUES ('$_POST[txtBrName]','$_POST[txtBrEmail]','$_POST[txtBrConNo]','$_POST[txtareaAddress]','$_POST[radioStatus]')";
    mysql_query($sql_branch,$link) or die(mysql_error($link));
    mysql_close($link);
    $url = WEB_URL . 'branch/branchlist.php?m=add';
    header("Location: $url");

    }
    else{

        //echo mysql_errno($link,mysql_query()) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n"; 

        $sql_branch = "UPDATE `tblbranch` SET `branch_name`='".$_POST['txtBrName']."',`b_email`='".$_POST['txtBrEmail']."',`b_contact_no`='".$_POST['txtBrConNo']."',`b_address`='".$_POST['txtareaAddress']."',`b_status` ='".$_POST['radioStatus']."' WHERE branch_id = '".$_GET['id']."'";
        mysql_query($sql_branch,$link);
        mysql_close($link);
        $url = WEB_URL . 'branch/branchlist.php?m=up';
        header("Location: $url");  
    }
```

This is the HTML code :

```
<form onSubmit="return validateMe();" action="<?php echo $form_url; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtBrName">Branch Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtBrName" id="txtBrName" value="<?php echo $branch_name; ?>" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtBrEmail">Email :</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtBrEmail" id="txtBrEmail" value="<?php echo $b_email; ?>" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtBrConNo">Contact No :</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtBrConNo" value="<?php echo $b_contact_no; ?>" id="txtBrConNo" class="form-control" />
      </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtareaAddress">Branch address :</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtareaAddress" value="<?php echo $b_address; ?>" id="txtareaAddress" class="form-control" />
      </div>
       <!--div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtStatus">Branch Status :</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtStatus" value="" id="b_status" class="form-control" />
      </div-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtBranch_status">Branch Status :</label>
        <!--input type="radio"  name="txtBranch_status" value="" id="b_status" class="form-control" /></br-->
          <input type="radio" name="radioStatus" value="Enable" id="radioStatus"> Enable
          <input type="radio" name="radioStatus" value="Disable" id="radioStatus"> Disable

      </div>

 <div class="form-group pull-right">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo $button_text; ?>"/>
            &nbsp;
            <input type="reset" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>branch/addbranch.php';" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="hdnSpid" value="<?php echo $hval; ?>"/>



  </form>
```

Comment: Can you please rewrite the code using the stackoverflow guide line for readability

Comment: You are open to SQL injections and please be more specific than `doesn't work`.

Comment: connection is working but when i try to update/insert i get nothing on the db

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your PHP code to find the error :

```
if(!mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tblbranch`(`branch_name`, `b_email`, `b_contact_no`, `b_address`,`b_status`) VALUES ('$_POST[txtBrName]','$_POST[txtBrEmail]','$_POST[txtBrConNo]','$_POST[txtareaAddress]','$_POST[radioStatus]')"")
{
echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if(isset($_POST['txtBrName'])){
    if(isset($_POST['hdn']) && $_POST['hdn'] == '0'){
        $branch_name = $_POST['txtBrName'];
        $b_email = $_POST['txtBrEmail'];
        $b_contact_no = $_POST['txtBrConNo'];
        $b_address = $_POST['txtareaAddress'];
        $b_status = $_POST['radioStatus'];
        $branch_id = $_GET['id'];

        $sql_branch = "INSERT INTO tblbranch (branch_name, b_email, b_contact_no, b_address,b_status) VALUES ('$branch_name', '$b_email', '$b_contact_no', '$b_address', '$b_status')";
        mysql_query($sql_branch,$link) or die(mysql_error($link));
        mysql_close($link);
        $url = WEB_URL . 'branch/branchlist.php?m=add';
        header("Location: $url");

    }
    else{

        //echo mysql_errno($link,mysql_query()) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n"; 

        $sql_branch = "UPDATE tblbranch SET branch_name='$branch_name', b_email ='$b_email', b_contact_no ='$b_contact_no', b_address ='$b_address', b_status ='$b_status' WHERE branch_id = '$branch_id'";
        mysql_query($sql_branch,$link);
        mysql_close($link);
        $url = WEB_URL . 'branch/branchlist.php?m=up';
        header("Location: $url");  
    }
}
```